# Passportjs local strategy missing credentials error message

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to implement authentication in node.js application using passportjs with passport-local strategy. I read documentation carefully and used all thing which were suggested into documentation. But I'm getting always "missing credential" message every time.

Node.js File:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'P@ssP0rtJs',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(require('flash')());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new localStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    var displayName = 'Test User',
        loginUsername = 'testuser',
        loginPassword = 'test',
        user = {
            "id": '1001',
            "display": displayName,
            "username": loginUsername,
            "password": loginPassword,
            "loggedin": '1'
        };
    if (loginUsername != username && loginPassword != password) {
        return done(null, false, {
            type: "error",
            message: 'Either username or password is wrong.'
        });
    }
    return done(null, user);
}));

// routes

/* GET Home page. */
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}), function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});

/* GET user login. */
app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Login'
    });
});

/* POST user login. */
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}), function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

/* GET logout page. */
app.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

var server = http.createServer(app).once('error', function (err) {
    if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
        console.log('port is currently in use');
    }
}).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    // console will print the message
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I did a lots search but couldn't find a solution from other post. When I saw console and find this output.

```
Express server listening on port 3000
GET /login 200 381.482 ms - 465
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.685 ms - -
POST /login 302 24.303 ms - 58
GET / 302 2.419 ms - 68
GET /login 200 32.336 ms - 528
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.563 ms - -
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "passport-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js $PORT"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "express-session": "~1.13.0",
    "passport": "~0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "flash": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the field name of username text box and password text box in login template?

Comment: @HirenS. I'm using name `username` for username input field and `password` for password input field. I know about options for overwrite input fields name in passport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`passport.authenticate('local')` middleware is used when you are trying to verify user credentials from POST body. So it should be used only for `POST /login` route. But you are also using this middleware in `GET /`, and thus the error, since this route doesn't have any POST body.

To check if a user is logged in, use `req.isAuthenticated()` method:

```
const isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
  else res.redirect('/login')

}
app.get('/', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});
```